# Don't save p-value/coefficient from glmer if there was a warning

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I'm running a for loop through a series of analyses. For some of these tests, `glmer` returns a warning message (copied below). I would like to not save the p-values or parameter estimates for these sites. I imagine this would be an if-statement with pseudocode resembling `if no warning, then print beta/p-value to tests`, but I can't figure out how to implement this. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

> Warning message:
>   In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
>   Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00778865 (tol = 0.001, component 1)

```
for (i in 1:10000) {
  test <- glmer(cbind(mcounts[i,], counts[i,] - mcounts[i,]) ~ pred + (1 |indiv), family = binomial)
  summary(test)$coefficients[2,4] -> tests[i,2]
  summary(test)$coefficients[2,1] -> tests[i,1]
}
```

Comment: quick suggestion - promote warnings to errors with `options(warn =  2)` (check help) and then use `try` or `trycatch` to deal with the errors

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, these are *warnings*, not *errors* (old-school R people tend to be fussy about this distinction: I edited your question accordingly, you can roll back the changes if you like). You can follow @RichardTelford's advice (in comment above), but you get greater precision if rather than upgrading *all* warnings to errors, you upgrade only gradient-convergence warnings (you also have the option to adjust the tolerance for this check).

I modified your code slightly for readability and robustness (e.g. refer to the components of the coefficient table you want by name rather than position).

```
 gcontrol <- glmerControl(check.conv.grad = .makeCC("error", tol = 2e-3))
 for (i in 1:10000) {
     test <- try(glmer(cbind(mcounts[i,], counts[i,] - mcounts[i,]) ~ 
                pred + (1 |indiv), family = binomial,
                control=gcontrol
                ))
     if (inherits(test,"try-error")) next ## if error skip to next iteration
     cc <- coef(summary(test))
     tests[i,] <- cc["pred",c("Estimate","Pr(>|z|)")]    
}
```

Make sure to fill the `tests` structure with `NA` values before you start: then you can easily see which tests failed, and strip the results down only to the successful tests (e.g.  with `na.omit(as.data.frame(tests))`).

It might be worth reading `?convergence`: I would probably set the tolerance for bad convergence to be somewhat higher (e.g. 0.02).

Comment: Wonderful, conceptually this seems perfect. However, in glmer, there's no option for 'control=gcontrol' and if I use glmerControl (as is suggested) there's no option for family=binomial. is control=gcontrol necessary here?

Comment: ??? I defined `gcontrol` in line 1 (just for easier readability). I don't understand what you mean by "if I use `glmerControl` there's no option for `family=binomial`. `control` is an argument to `glmer`. `glmerControl()` is a function that returns a list suitable passing to `control`. `family` is a separate argument to `glmer`.

Comment: Oh, I'm a complete idiot and missed that line. Thank you!